# SQLCMD "!!" not working in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sqlcmd, sql-server-2017

I just installed SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition. I then run this command through SQLCMD.

```
:!!time /T
PRINT "Hello world!
```

... and I don't get any output at all. This should display the time and print `Hello world!`. When I comment the first line, `Hello world!` is displayed correctly.

I can't see any changes or documentations around this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you execute this from SSMS? When I run your code on my SQL Server 2017 instance, it all works.

Comment: This is executed using SQLCMD v14.0. I did some research, that they are trying to have support on other platform as well, and because of that, [!!] commands does not work, but, this is just a theory. :(

Comment: can you share if you got it working finally?

Comment: Same answer as below, run in lower version for now. But also going forward, find other ways to avoid !! commands.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem in our CI solution, and got it working with a workaround in our environment.

The workaround is to install the 2012 version of the SQL Server Command Line tools (think it is Version 11), and to ensure it is in the PATH environment variable before the 2017 tools (Version 14). Version 12 or 13 (SQL 2014 or 2016) might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sqlcmd try to use SQLS*Plus from http://www.sqlsplus.com. The tool works like Oracle's SQL*Plus but for SQL Server. It is free for a single instance - check the website.